# Oracle job not executing automatically after 30 seconds

Tags: oracle9i

I have created this Job to run a procedure. I expect it to run automatically after 30 seconds from the first execution but it does not. What could be the issue. The Job runs if I execute Manually. I am using 9i

```
DECLARE
  X NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
    ( job       => X 
     ,what      => 'ALERT_GNARATE;'
     ,next_date => to_date('25/11/2011 11:43:35','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
     ,interval  => 'SYSDATE+1/2880'
     ,no_parse  => TRUE
    );
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Number is: ' || to_char(x));
END;
```

Comment: Do you really intend the `next_date` to be a value that is 4.5 years ago?  I'm not clear if you are saying it runs once automatically successfully or whether it never runs.  What are the results of querying `dba_jobs` for this job?  What is `job_queue_processes` set to?

Comment: Nope that date is actually todays date in the actual job. it is not running at all unless I execute it manually.